# Shuffle an array of int in C with - without while loop

Tags: c, loops, random, while-loop, shuffle

I want to Shuffle an array of ints, the array is sorted and its size in n, values are 1 - n.
I Just want to avoid using a while loop in order to make sure the rand() doesn't give me the same index.
the code looks somthin like this:

```
void shuffleArr(int* arr, size_t n)
{
  int newIndx = 0;
  int i = 0;

  for(; i < n - 1; ++i)
  {
    while((newIndx = i + rand() % (n - i)) == i);

    swap(i, newIndx, arr);
  }
}
```

The for loop goes until n-1, so for example in the last run it has 50/50 chance of being equal to i. I want to avoid this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are searching for a random number in range 1...n but excluding some number m in that range, you can instead get a random number in range 1...(n-1) and for any result >= m add 1 to the value.

If you are looking for an explanation of an algorithm for shuffling a finite list, take a look at Fisher-Yates here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Tnx first. But, with Fisher-Yates, i still do not check if the number i randomed equals to the index.

Comment: Right, unless I'm mistaken, in Fisher-Yates you go through each item in turn and decide a new random position for it to take excluding the positions that have already been decided. However, it seems valid that there be a chance that the new shuffled position is the same as its current position.

Comment: Exactly my point. This is why I wanted the while loop, in order to avoid this situation. But, at the last run it will be 50 50 chance as i said, and hypothetically speaking it can be infinite loop even then.

Comment: I'm not sure if we are on the same page -- do you agree it is valid to shuffle an element to its current position or are you trying to eliminate that? If you want to eliminate it and bias the shuffle in that way then is there something wrong with the method in the first paragraph of my answer?

Comment: Got you now. I believe I didn't quiet understand you first answer. Yes, I do want to eliminate this situation, and after each to check if(res = rand() % (n - 1) >= i) then ++res. You are correct.

Comment: But it leads me to this problem that I posted just now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101261/shuffle-an-array-while-making-each-index-have-the-same-probability-to-be-in-any , where there might be a chance that some indexes will go back to their first place, thus no change/shuffle was made. I do want it to be all shuffled and moved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, it involves a little bit of both.

```
void Shuffle(int[] arr, size_t n)
{
  int newIndx = 0;
  int i = 0;

  for(; i < n - 2; ++i)
  {
    newIndx = i + rand() % (n - i);
    if(newIndx == i)
    {
      ++newIndx;
    }

    swap(i, newIndx, arr);
  }
}
```

No need to loop until there is a good (random number != i), cuz it is fixed with the if + increment of newIndx.